# Which gender XT60 connector on battery?

Tags: battery-charging, connector, lithium-ion, short-circuit

What is the recommended plug on the battery?

The male or the female XT60 and why?

[XT60 connector](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51NO64yKj8L._AC_SL1000_.jpg)

Comment: What kind of battery do you plan to use? Massive high power battery or liltte coin batteries like coin cell?

Comment: @emreiris You're gonna need a bigger... coin cell :D Much bigger.

Comment: @Maple Yeah :) . I wanted to point that connectors should be chosen according to battery power.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Batteries are always connected with the female connector.

This is always the convention for power sources. Consider dropping a paperclip or small coin onto the connector. The male connector could easily be short-circuited by that. The female connector however needs a fairly unusual shape of conductor to draw power from it.

Comment: i need a clarification . When i look at  the picture , the female housing xt60 has 2 male electrical contact , and the male housing has 2 female electrical contact . So when you refer to the female connector , you refer to the contact not the housing ?

Comment: That makes sense. Now please tell me which pin should be + and which -. I've searched everywhere and can't find an answer.

Comment: @RobLewis `I've searched everywhere and can't find an answer.` Put 'XT60' into google. Several images at the top of the page show a housing, with its polarisation clear, and red (positive) and back (negative) leads connected to it. Several youtube videos also come up showing the connections. Appallingly, also on the first page is an RSPro datasheet, which doesn't show the polarity. However, now search for 'XT60 datasheet', and you'll have more polarity indicating results than you can shake a stick at. Positive is at the flat end.

Comment: Funnily enough, I bought one of those big lithium battery "power center" boxes. One of its several DC outputs is a MALE XT60. I explained to them that this is wrong but they seem unmoved. Might have something to do with the difficulty of finding a *panel-mount* female XT60—all the ones I've found are cord-mount. At any rate I built myself a short female-female adapter cord and I'm good to go.

Comment: @Neil_UK: Unfortunately one of the top hits is https://components101.com/connectors/xt60-connector which has contradictory polarity information IN A SINGLE IMAGE.  I believe the numbered pin instructions are correct and the arrows are wrong?